# Why is it not a commit and a branch cannot be created from it?

Tags: git, git-non-bare-repository

I need to work with an intricate configuration of repositories. I have 5 of them:

1. A remote central repository on machine 1.
2. My local repository on my notebook (machine 2).
3. A bare repository on machine 3.
4. A repository on machine 3.
5. A repository on machine 4 where we do code review.

So, my understanding that it works this way:

1. On my laptop (machine 2) I clone / pull from the central repository located on machine 1.
2. I push the local repo to the machine 3 (using the bare repository as a "intermediate").

Now I did some changes on the machine 3 and I want to push these changes to machine 4. Here are the instructions that I need to follow:

1. On machine 3 do all work in your test-branch, commit.
2. Push to your bare repo on machine 3: git push origin test-branch
3. On your laptop: fetch new commits from the machine-3 repo: git fetch machine3
4. Check out your branch from machine 3: git checkout -b test-branch machine-3/test-branch
5. Fetch commits from machine-4: git fetch origin
6. git rebase origin/master
7. git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

I have problems with step 4. I get the following error:

> fatal: 'machine3/test-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'test-branch' cannot be created from it

**ADDED**

When I execute

```
git rev-parse machine3/test-branch
```

On my laptop (machine 2) I get:

> machine3/test-branch
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument 'machine3/test-branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>
> ```
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> ```

Comment: The repo of Machine 3 is bare, which means it does not have any working tree.  `git checkout -b test-branch machine-3/test-branch` needs a working tree, so it fails. Besides, you need to check if `machine3/test-branch` exists. https://mijingo.com/blog/what-is-the-working-tree-in-git

Comment: On machine 3 I have 2 repos (one bare and another one is non-bare). I have the "test-branch" in the non-bare repo on machine 3.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. What does `git rev-parse machine3/test-branch` echo?

Comment: In what git should I execute it?

Comment: In the repo where you run Step 4.

Comment: I have updated my question with the answer to you question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166889/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-roman).

Comment: what about git pull?

Comment: @CharlieParker I have addressed your comment in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65756155/6309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is complex / convolute, the answer is simple. There was a mismatch between the alias and machine3. The alias for the remote that has been used, was not for machine3. The machine3 had another alias.

Comment: For me the same error occured when I made a spelling mistake in my remote branch name.

Answer (score 204):

For those who found this searching for an answer to `fatal: 'origin/remote-branch-name' is not a commit and a branch 'local-branch-name' cannot be created from it`, you may also want to try this first:

```
git fetch --all
```

If you run `git checkout -b local-branch-name origin/remote-branch-name` without `fetch`ing first, you can run into that error.

The reason it says "is not a commit" rather than something clearer like "branch doesn't exist" is because git takes the argument where you specified `origin/remote-branch-name` and tries to resolve it to a commit hash. You can use tag names and commit hashes as an argument here, too. If they fail, it generates the same error. If git can't resolve the branch you provide to a specific commit, it's usually because it doesn't have the freshest list of remote branches. `git fetch --all` fixes that scenario.

The `--all` flag is included in case you have multiple remotes (e.g. `origin`, `buildserver`, `joespc`, etc.), because `git fetch` by itself defaults to your first remote-- usually `origin`. You can also run `fetch` against a specific remote; e.g., `git fetch buildserver` will only fetch all the branches from the `buildserver` remote.

To list all your remotes, run the command `git remote -v`. You can omit the `--all` flag from `git fetch` if you only see one remote name (e.g. `origin`) in the results.

Comment: for me `git fetch origin` `git fetch origin master` did not help, I had to `git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: @SillyFreak that's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: @SillyFreak - I was failing to create an tracking branch for an upstream but it started working after : 
git fetch upstream refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/upstream/My-Remote-Branch-Name

Comment: what about git pull?

Comment: @CharlieParker `git pull` is just a shortcut command for `git fetch && git merge origin/master` or whatever your current remote name / remote branch is. So, yes, it would work, too.

Answer (score 71):

We had this error:

```
fatal: 'origin/newbranch' is not a commit and a branch 'newbranch' cannot be created from it
```

because we did a minimalistic clone using:

```
git  clone  --depth 1  --branch 'oldbranch'  --single-branch  'git@github.com:user/repo.git'
```

For us the minimalistic fix was:

```
git  remote  set-branches  --add  'origin'  'newbranch'
git  fetch  'origin'
git  checkout  --track  'origin/newbranch'
```

Assuming the remote is called 'origin' and the remote branch is called 'newbranch'.

Comment: Thank you! Been running in circles for an hour till I found your answer :)

Comment: I cloned single branch and failed when tracking new branch, this help me so much.

Comment: At least someone understands that git repo can be GINORMOUS and using 'git fetch --all' is not an option

Comment: In my case, this solution only worked for me among answers of this question.

Comment: what about git pull?

Answer (score 19):

I managed to fix this with this settings, just update the config with this command

`git config -e --global`

and add this config.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git.example.com/example.git (you can omit this URL)
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and then you can `git fetch --all`

Comment: It worked for me too. I had remove my only remote to get rid of all tracking branches at once, and that line was gone.

Comment: thanks, it solves my issue for fetching remote branches.

Comment: it worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 6):

I found this question troubleshooting simpler problem: I recieved same error trying to create a lobal branch from remote.
I resolved it by creating branch from commit hash:

```
git ls-remote origin remote-branch
returned
<hash>  refs/heads/remote-branch

git checkout -b local-branch <hash>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're checking out a branch from a tag (like `git checkout -b XXXX v0.1.1`) , you can try `git fetch --tags` first.

Answer (score 1):

We were having this exact error in a Windows machine running gitbash on a folder   synced with google drive.

**It was caused by having the feature "Enable experimental built-in file system monitor" enabled.**

After uninstalling and reinstalling gitbash with this feature disabled it was fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this issue:

```
fatal: 'machine3/test-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'test-branch' cannot be created from it
```

For me, I should have checked out to `test-branch` first, then it worked fine and created a new branch from `test-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem where I `git checkout name-branch` and it was created but when i
check the branch with `git branch`  nothing happens
after hours of trying to figure out I tried to run the command `git push GitHub-URL name-branch`
and it pushes the commit directly to the branch
hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My issues was I had a ***space*** in my new branch name

Issue:

`git checkout -b my-new-branch name`

instead of

`git checkout -b my-new-branch-name`

Answer (score 0):

The branch does not exist on the remote origin specified. Double check: You might be trying to pull oranges from a grapes tree.

Answer (score 0):

Check your git config in .git folder, and validate this content

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    fileMode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/ABC/project0001.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[pull]
    ff = no
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

`[remote "origin"]` <-- this section

Answer (score 0):

For those who found this searching for an answer to `fatal: 'origin/remote-branch-name' is not a commit and a branch 'local-branch-name' cannot be created from it`, another possibility we just found is the remote branch has been merged already :embarrassed:

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this when I used the "copy" tool on GitHub next to the branch name of a coworker's PR. His branch was named like `coworker/ticket-number` and `git checkout --track coworker/ticket-number` was what came out of the paste.

When I went back to my usual workflow, using `git branch -r | grep ticket-number` I found that the actual branch name I needed to use was `origin/coworker/ticket-number`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and the fix was as simple as creating teh branch in two steps:

1. git checkout the existing branch from where I want to create my new branch.
   e.g. git checkout dev
   This brings you to the dev branch.
2. create the new branch from dev branch while sitting on the dev branch
   e.g. git checkout -b <new_feature_branch> dev

Answer (score 0):

I generally create the branches via UI on gitlab/github and then switch to it in local.

I was running this command

```
git fetch origin
git checkout --track origin/my-branch
```

And I got the same error
`fatal: 'origin/my-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'my-branch' cannot be created from it`

It turns out, `my-branch` didn't exist on the remote repository. I had mistakenly created it on another repo via UI.

Answer (score -1):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55406283/6309) from [J.D. Mallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986790/j-d-mallen) involves `git fetch --all`

Starting with VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021), you will have ([issue 110811](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110811) and [PR 111090](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/111090)):

> Changing `autofetch` to a string config which has "`current`", "`all`" and "`off`".
>
> This allows users to fetch from **all remotes** instead of just their `origin`.
> For developers working on a Fork, this should make extensions work more intuitively.

So if you set the VSCode setting `git.autofetch` to "`all`", you won't even have to type `git fetch --all`.

---

[Charlie Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601580/charlie-parker) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297153/why-is-it-not-a-commit-and-a-branch-cannot-be-created-from-it?noredirect=1#comment132349480_49297153):

> What about `git pull`?

That supposes you are on a current branch with a remote tracking branch already set up.

The original question does not have such a branch in place, which means git pull would not know what to merge from fetched branches.

Answer (score -2):

I used git workflow in visual studio code as shown in the below diagram to solve mine:

[image: create a feature branch using git on vscode]

Comment: why is the answer voted down pls? I'd like to know, afterall I only mentioned the way I solve a similar problem.