# Git error "fatal: XXX is not a commit and a branch YYY cannot be created from it

Tags: git, github

I am trying the checkout a branch from a remote repository into a local branch, and receive the above error.

For those who want to direct me to:
[Why is it not a commit and a branch cannot be created from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297153/why-is-it-not-a-commit-and-a-branch-cannot-be-created-from-it), then I already tried fetching, and even
`git fetch --all`

To be precise, I cannot checkout any branch on the Github repository, that is not the main branch that I'm tracking, let's call it `dev`.

So, I can do the following:

```
git checkout origin/dev -b my_own_dev_env
```

But I cannot checkout any other branch, not even

```
git checkout origin/master -b master
```

And in this case I receive

> "fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and a branch 'master' cannot
>   be created from it"

Edit:
When cloning to a new directory, I can perform all git operations as usual.
So I would like to know what could go wrong in a local copy that prevents git commands from working properly?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information. Lets start with, can you checkout your branch if you create a clean clone of the remote? Can you confirm that the branch exists on the remote? What's the configuration of origin, etc. ?

Comment: (1) What is that backslash doing in your quoted text? Typo in pasting the error message? (Use cut-and-paste to avoid typos.) (2) Did you use `git clone --single-branch` originally?

Comment: @Liam, thanks, after cloning the repo again, I can checkout any branch I want. So still, I would like to work on the same local directory I was working on. What is preventing me from checking out branches?

Comment: @torek - (1) thanks, edited.   (2) not, I cloned without the ```single_branch``` option.

Comment: Hm, it's certainly *acting like* a single-branch clone, if `git fetch` does not create-or-update the appropriate remote-tracking names. What goes `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` produce?

Comment: @torek, it produces: ```+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev```. I think I need ```*```,  so how can I revert configuration to *  ?

Comment: Aha. That's the setting for `--single-branch`. If you didn't use `git clone --depth` or `git clone --single-branch`, you must have set it some other way. Set this back to normal, and `git fetch` will make `git checkout work again. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17714159/1256452

Comment: Incredible! Probably my PyCharm changed something in the background. I didn't issue the ```single_branch``` command in the command line. You are invited to write it as an answer and I'll mark it as the best one that could help.

Answer (score 8):

First check whether you have fetched all branches or not by executing following command.

```
git fetch --all
```

Check for existence of branch name in local

```
git branch -a
```

Execute command to track remote branch and create one in local

```
git checkout -t origin/<Branch Name>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have limited fetch configurations for your remote. See `.git/config` for your remote, it may have something like the following.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main
```

As such `git fetch` will only get `main`. To fix you can update it to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```